# Reference for cocommutative coalgebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, coalgebras

I'm looking for references on cocommutative coalgebras where I can see them as kind of infinitesimal spaces. I'm trying to understand this post [Why do Lie algebras pop up, from a categorical point of view?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177037/why-do-lie-algebras-pop-up-from-a-categorical-point-of-view)